# Best way to notify a user on Facebook that it's their turn to act

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a turn-based game that I'd like to integrate into Facebook.  Players may not necessarily be playing in real time so having a way for them to know when it's their turn is desirable.

I was initially thinking facebook notifications, but it appears that has been deprecated:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619164/how-to-send-a-facebook-notification-through-their-api

The alternatives don't sound terribly pleasant (writing on their wall, or having the player that just finished their turn send a request)

Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: By not real time, do you mean that the players may have it open as a tab but may be multi-tasking? Or am I completely off?

Comment: @DMan that's one option, or maybe the players' schedules don't align and can't be online at the same time, so one player plays their turn, then goes do something else (possibly plays a game with a different player) then comes back after their opponent has made their move.

So kinda like play by email like what's built into Civilization IV and is also (relatively) popular with Chess.  I already have email as an option, but I wanted to provide an alternative on Facebook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requests were created for this purpose among others...

> App-generated requests: These requests can be initiated and sent only
>   to users who have authorized your app. Developers can send these
>   requests using the Graph API. Use these requests to update the
>   bookmark count to encourage a user to re-engage in the app **(e.g., your
>   friend finished her move in a game and it’s now your turn)**.

See: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/

Comment: Ah, I think I just automatically assumed that requests had to be user initiated, and you're right, this is exactly the purpose of requests!  (Why did you make the answer a community wiki though?)

Comment: Uh, is that bad? I'm pretty clueless :)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't allow applications to send direct messages. I think there is no way to generate a notification with an app on facebook, you can only write on the users wall.

Maybe your best solution is to send an SMS, email or use twitter.

Comment: From that page and the comments it sounds like it's only for reading messages not for sending them.  The required permission to use that feature is "read_mailbox" so it doesn't sound like it's intended to send.

Comment: Yea you are right, and I remember reading sometime ago that facebook didn't let applications send direct messages.